# How to select all id's rows where all sequence is present?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table like below :

```
DT1 <- data.table(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
  sensor_id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3),
  time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-01 00:06:35","2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 22:00:20","2017-01-02 22:01:09","2017-01-02 22:28:02","2017-01-03 22:23:01","2017-01-03 22:50:52")
  )
```

From this, I want to select all the customer_id rows which have all the sequences of sensor id's (1,2,3) in this case.

So I want to label these like below :

```
DT1 <- data.table(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
  sensor_id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3),
  time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-01 00:06:35","2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 22:00:20","2017-01-02 22:01:09","2017-01-02 22:28:02","2017-01-03 22:23:01","2017-01-03 22:50:52"),
  group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  seq_boolean=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
)
```

where I can identify the row is having all the sequences or not.
One **id** can appear multiple times and also not have all the sequences.

So for this, I tried the below to group first

```
DT1[,group:=rleid(id),by=list(id,rleid(sensor_id))]
```

But this just groups all as one. I am not sure where I am doing it wrong. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT
I can also have data tables like in the below format.

```
DT1 <- data.table(
       id=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1),
       sensor_id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3),
       time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-01 00:06:35","2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 00:00:20","2017-01-02 00:35:09","2017-01-02 00:28:02","2017-01-03 00:45:01","2017-01-03 00:50:52")
   )
```

Here the group is defined by sensor_id.sensor_id 1 is start of the session and sensor_id 2 is the middle session and sensor_id 3 is the end of the session. An id can have multiple sessions and some sensors might fail to capture the id. So my purpose is to identify all the sessions captured by all 3 sensor ids and see how much is being captured.

Comment: For your EDIT data, my answer still gives the expected output right?

Comment: sorry again edited wrongly. The test cases I am trying to include is that sensor 1 is the start and sensor 3 is the end of a session for an id. But some might start with sensor 2 and end with 3. So need to identify(group column to take count) and remove them is my purpose.

Comment: I think this example is still not accurate as my original answer still works on this but I think I understand you now. Can you check my edited answer?

Comment: Extremely Sorry there is an issue while copying. I think we cannot simply group it by rleid for the id.identification of start and end is required right?

Comment: do you want to start a new session whenever there is a 3? maybe something like `DT1[, g := shift(cumsum(sensor_id==3L), fill=0L), id][, 
    group := .GRP, .(id, g)]`

Comment: How do you define one group? Till now I was under the impression that `rleid(id)` is enough to define groups.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I added a description in the question . That's why I was sensing rleid(id) is not enough.

Comment: @Ricky Check my updated answer with `dplyr`. Hopefully I have understood it clearly this time.

Comment: @chinsoon12 yeah the grouping is correctly done with your method. But for a generic solution can I also add the start session identifier. Because now I can identify the session based on the end sensor_id.

Comment: Yup just use cumsum without shift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check if all the `uniq_sensor` is present for each group.

```
uniq_sensor <- unique(DT1$sensor_id)
DT1[, seq_boolean := +(all(uniq_sensor %in% sensor_id)), rleid(id)]
DT1

#   id sensor_id                time seq_boolean
#1:  1         1 2017-01-01 00:00:05           1
#2:  1         2 2017-01-01 00:06:35           1
#3:  1         3 2017-01-01 00:23:44           1
#4:  2         1 2017-01-02 22:00:20           1
#5:  2         2 2017-01-02 22:01:09           1
#6:  2         3 2017-01-02 22:28:02           1
#7:  1         2 2017-01-03 22:23:01           0
#8:  1         3 2017-01-03 22:50:52           0
```

We can also count the length of unique sensors for each group :

```
DT1[, seq_boolean := +(uniqueN(sensor_id) == length(uniq_sensor)), rleid(id)]
```

---

**EDIT**

For the additional condition where we want to make sure that the `sensor_id` occurs in exact same order we can do :

```
library(dplyr)

DT1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(sensor_id) <= 0)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  #Use add = TRUE for old dplyr < 1.0.0
  mutate(seq_boolean = +(all(uniq_sensor %in% sensor_id)))
```

Comment: Thanks,for intro to the all function .Yeah but is there also a way to create the group column.I was trying it to create it first and then create seq_boolean .

Comment: @Ricky Just do `DT1[, group := rleid(id)]` first and use `group` in above answer?

Comment: yes I tried this but this only works if the data table is in the given format. Sometimes I have data tables in the form of if I apply `DT1=DT1[order(time)]` then this will not work. In those cases, how do I transform into this because `DT1[order(id,time)]` this one doesn't produce in the above format.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. `DT1` is already sorted by `time`, so I don't think anything changes with `DT1=DT1[order(time)]`.

Comment: oops, my bad if it ordered by `id` like  `DT1=DT1[order(id)]`  and if sort by time then cannot preserve each id to be in order.

Comment: In such cases how do you know that first 3 rows is 1 group and next 2 rows in another when their `id`'s are consecutive.

Comment: Here the logic you use for `grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(sensor_id) <= 0)` is still not identifying the group for each id for start and end right? it is only grouping all ids together not all id's session separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
DT1[,seq_boolean := +setequal(sensor_id, DT1[, sensor_id]), by = rleid(id)]
DT1
   id sensor_id                time seq_boolean
1:  1         1 2017-01-01 00:00:05           1
2:  1         2 2017-01-01 00:06:35           1
3:  1         3 2017-01-01 00:23:44           1
4:  2         1 2017-01-02 22:00:20           1
5:  2         2 2017-01-02 22:01:09           1
6:  2         3 2017-01-02 22:28:02           1
7:  1         2 2017-01-03 22:23:01           0
8:  1         3 2017-01-03 22:50:52           0
```